# Highcharts Navigator Zoom

Tags: highcharts

I use highcharts, and i just added my navigator. By default it is 100% zoomed out. I have the buttons for my timespans already from my JSP so i do not want to use rangeSelector. How can i programmaticaly zoom in to a specific span of my series?

For example when i click the 5 years button i fetch data for 10 years and i display it all in the chart cause i am 100% zoomed out. What i want is to zoom in to show data for 5 years but still have all the data of the 10 years rendered just in case i wanna zoom out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the `setExtremes` method for `xAxis`

```
chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(min, max);
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/f394h8ps/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#setExtremes

Comment: Thanks for your reply. May i ask why do we get to use setTimeout? Will try to implement it now and update with result!

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks. I just had a problem with my scope (this.chart didnt work inside setTimeout so i just used it without setTimeout)

Comment: Hi @Christopher Vradis, I used `setTimeout` only for better demonstrating the action.

Comment: Just to clarify for anyone who reads this post, min max are Date UTC values.